# Execute statement that is stored inside a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

As example I will create a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TembTable  
(
      Command VARCHAR(max)  
)
```

Insert the values toin the table

```
INSERT INTO #TembTable (Command)
VALUES ('SELECT @@VERSION AS Version_Name ;'),
       ('SELECT @@LANGUAGE AS Current_Language;'),
       ('SELECT @@LANGID AS Language_ID ;'),
       ('SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS Server_Name;'),
       ('SELECT @@SERVICENAME AS Service_Name;')
```

If I select all values

```
SELECT * FROM #TembTable
```

Result will show:

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS Version_Name ;
SELECT @@LANGUAGE AS Current_Language;
SELECT @@LANGID AS Language_ID ;
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS Server_Name;
SELECT @@SERVICENAME AS Service_Name;
```

What I am trying to do is to execute each command automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: To run SQL stored in a table, you need a loop to process multiple rows one at a time, and then `sp_executesql` to execute the dynamic SQL.

Comment: You may also want to have a temp table that has an ORDER - not a random one as you ahve. i.e. add an ID field so you can execute them ordered by ID. Otherwise you may or may not get them in the same order when retrieving.

Comment: Why not simply create a view? `create view ... as select @@version as version_name, @@language as current_language, ...`

Answer (score 2):

You must declare a variable

```
DECLARE @Statements NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

Fill this variable with the commands from #Temptable

```
SET @Statements = ( SELECT STRING_AGG (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),Command), NCHAR(13)) 
                    FROM   #TembTable)
;
```

and execute it:

```
EXECUTE (@Statements)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A select query is a database object that shows information in Datasheet view. A query does not store data, it displays data that is stored in tables. A query can show data from one or more tables, from other queries, or from a combination of the two. ([https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-simple-select-query-de8b1c8d-14e9-4b25-8e22-70888d54de59#:~:text=A%20select%20query%20is%20a,a%20combination%20of%20the%20two](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-simple-select-query-de8b1c8d-14e9-4b25-8e22-70888d54de59#:%7E:text=A%20select%20query%20is%20a,a%20combination%20of%20the%20two))

If your intention is to get the values for the statements then you can incorporate a stored procedure to do the above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Getdetails
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @@VERSION AS Version_Name ;
    SELECT @@LANGUAGE AS Current_Language;
    SELECT @@LANGID AS Language_ID ;
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS Server_Name;
    SELECT @@SERVICENAME AS Service_Name;
END;
```

to get o/p: The below will retrieve all details that you needed

`exec Getdetails`